# Internal Server Error when adding new Fields

Tags: craft3, field, error-message

I was adding new fields to my Craft 3 install using the field manager plugin. Suddenly I am seeing a Internal Server Error when trying to access the admin area.

The front end looks fine. Anyone know how I can quickly resolve?

**In web.log I get**

```
Setting unknown property: craft\behaviors\ContentBehavior::announcementLink in /home/forge/www.uk-cpi.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:163
```

**In phperrors.log I get**

```
An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: craft\behaviors\ContentBehavior::announcementLink in /home/forge/www.uk-cpi.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php:163
```

`announcementLink` is the name of the field I was adding

Answer (score 1):

Solution

Login to the server and access mysql and find your database.

1. Select the fields table to locate the ID of the problem field.

   SELECT * FROM fields;
2. Remove the field using the ID.

   DELETE from fields where id = '355';